# How to store the name of child class in audits "auditable_type" column in single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, audit, sti

I am using single table inheritance in rails, and I am auditing the parent class. Whenever, I create/update the child class/model, auditable type for that audit stores the name of the parent class instead of the name of the child class .

Is this feature of audited intended, or is it just a side effect of STI ? 
What are the ways in which I could know the more specific auditable type in Single table inheritance?
This is some piece of code that I am writing.

```
class TdrDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
end

class InternationCc < TdrDetail

end
```

Whenever any record is created/updated/deleted for InternationCc, the auditable_type in the created audit is TdrDetail.

How can store the more specific type in the audits table?
TIA.

Comment: Could you provide the proof code w/ output, please?